# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interactive' (Converting Mercurial repository to Git)

Tags: python-3.x, git, mercurial, version-control-migration

I have a mercurial repository named "climate-sensitivity-gcm" that I am attempting to convert to git using the fast-export method in a Linux terminal. I enter the following in my command line:

```
$ ~/fast-export/hg-fast-export.sh -r /home/brandonsmith/climate-sensitivity-gcm/
```

the following errors get kicked back, along with the git-fast-import statistics:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nazko/home/brandonsmith/fast-export/hg2git.py", line 31, in setup_repo
    myui=ui.ui(interactive=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interactive'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nazko/home/brandonsmith/fast-export/hg-fast-export.py", line 529, in <module>
    notes=options.notes,encoding=encoding,fn_encoding=fn_encoding))
  File "/nazko/home/brandonsmith/fast-export/hg-fast-export.py", line 403, in hg2git
    ui,repo=setup_repo(repourl)
  File "/nazko/home/brandonsmith/fast-export/hg2git.py", line 34, in setup_repo
    myui.setconfig('ui', 'interactive', 'off')
  File "/home/brandonsmith/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/ui.py", line 553, in setconfig
    cfg.set(section, name, value, source)
  File "/home/brandonsmith/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mercurial/config.py", line 96, in set
    ), b'config section may not be unicode strings on Python 3'
AssertionError: b'config section may not be unicode strings on Python 3'
git-fast-import statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Alloc'd objects:       5000
Total objects:            0 (         0 duplicates                  )
      blobs  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      trees  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      commits:            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      tags   :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
Total branches:           0 (         0 loads     )
      marks:           1024 (         0 unique    )
      atoms:              0
Memory total:          2282 KiB
       pools:          2048 KiB
     objects:           234 KiB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pack_report: getpagesize()            =       4096
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize = 1073741824
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      = 8589934592
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =          0
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =          0
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          0 /          0
pack_report: pack_mapped              =          0 /          0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't understand what these errors mean nor what is wrong with my attempt to convert my hg-repo to a git-repo. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The hg2git.py script is using mercurial's python API directly. Mercurial has no stable python API and can change from version to version. If you want this to work you'll need to use a version of mercurial that is known to work with this script.